# How can Spark work in cluster mode with local master?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working on a Spark application (2.3.4) in Scala on a 2-nodes cluster and I'm experimenting with unexpected behavior.

In my code the SparkSession is created with a hardcoded master:

```
        val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .appName("MyApp")
        .master("local[*])
        .getOrCreate()
```

The code is then packed in a jar and submitted.
When I submit the job, if I try to set the deploy-mode to "cluster",

```
spark-submit --class MyClass--deploy-mode cluster --driver-memory 5g --conf spark.driver.cores=2 --conf spark.cores.max=2  myJar.jar
```

I get an expected error:

```
Error: Cluster deploy mode is not compatible with master "local" Run with --help for usage help or --verbose for debug output
```

But if I try to add a different master to the submission command,

```
spark-submit --class MyClass --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://172.xx.x.xx:7077 --driver-memory 5g --conf spark.driver.cores=2 --conf spark.cores.max=2  myJar.jar
```

I had an unexpected behavior. I know that Properties set directly on the SparkConf take the highest precedence with respect to ones written in the spark-submit. So I thought that in some way the configuration add in the submission command was taking precedence.
But printing the configurations from the SparkSession at runtime produces this:
[image]

So, it looks incompatible to me that the master is set to local and the deploy-mode to cluster.

Another thing that I'm struggling to understand is why when I submit the job in that way only a driver and no application is shown in the Spark Master monitoring page.

[image]

I'm pretty sure that I'm not understanding or using something properly, I consulted several resources but could not resolve my doubt. Can someone try to explain it to me?

Thanks in advance